# Amalgamating zip codes using Python Parser of ArcGIS Pro Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, field-calculator, python-parser

I'm fairly new to Python and I'm trying to amalgamate the zip codes from the fields of !OWADR2!, !OWADR3!, and !OWADR4! into a new field I've created. Basically I want to make a block of code in the new field's "calculate field" that checks if the last 5 characters of each address field is a string of numbers and pulls it if it is, but if it isn't it will iterate to the next address and so on.

With my limited knowledge of Python this is what I came up with:

In the expression field:

```
zipcodepull(!OWADR2![-5:], !OWADR3![-5:], !OWADR4![-5:])
```

and in the code block:

```
def zipcodepull(zip1, zip2, zip3):
   if zip1 == int:
      return zip1
   elif zip2 == int:
      return zip2
   elif zip3 == int:
      return zip3
   else:
      return int(0)
```

And here are the fields I'm pulling from:
[image]

Comment: As a starting point, I think you will need to use type() method to check the data type of a variable. zip1.type() = 'int'    or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you replace

```
zipcodepull(!OWADR2![-5:], !OWADR3![-5:], !OWADR4![-5:])
```

with

```
zipcodepull(!OWADR2!, !OWADR3!, !OWADR4!)
```

And each if elif with for example:

```
if zip1[-5:].isnumeric():
    return int(zip1[-5:])
```

Your code should work

Comment: Thank you so much, this has been astoundingly helpful